# Swift: How to make Generics code more clean

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types, type-alias

I'm searching for the way to make my code more clean and efficient.
I Have an "BaseInfo" it has got some properties and also it is a parent to the "SomeInfo", and "AnotherInfo" classes, which have own additional properties. I've made a generic function that saves and gets those objects from UserDefaults. And I have ViewController that's saves and loads info using those functions, considering the type of info it should use. I want to know is there any way to make my code cleaner and get rid of those type casting in my ViewContoller. Here is my info classes:

```
public class  BaseInfo: Codable{
    var name: String?
    
    init(_ dict: [String: Any]){
        
        name = dict["name"] as? String
    }
}

class AnotherInfo: BaseInfo {
    var secondName: String?
    
    override init(_ dict: [String : Any]) {
        super.init(dict)
        secondName = dict["secondName"] as? String
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class SomeInfo: BaseInfo {
    var middleName: String?
    
    
    override init(_ dict: [String : Any]) {
        super.init(dict)
        middleName = dict["middleName"]
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is my class that manages info

```
protocol InfoManagerProtocol {
    static func getInfo(with type: InfoType) -> BaseInfo?
    static func saveInfo <T: BaseInfo>(with type: InfoType, info: T)
}

class InfoManager: InfoManagerProtocol {
    
    static func getInfo<T: BaseInfo>(with type: InfoType) -> T? {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: type.toString()) as? Data, let info = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type.typeOfInfo() as! T.Type, from: data){
            return info
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    
    static func saveInfo<T>(with type: InfoType, info: T) where T : BaseInfo {
        if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(info){
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(encodedData, forKey: type.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

InfoType enum:

```
enum InfoType: Int{
    case base = 1
    case another = 2
    case some = 3
}

extension InfoType{

    func toString() -> String{
      switch self{
       case .base: 
           return "base"
       case .another: 
           return "another"
       case .some:
           return "some"
      }
    } 
    func typeOfInfo() -> BaseInfo.Type{
        switch self{
        case .base:
            return BaseInfo.self
        case .another:
            return AnotherInfo.self
        case .some:
            return SomeInfo.self
        }
    }
}
```

and some controller

```
class ViewCV: UIViewController{
    ......
    // some outlets
    var infoType: InfoType? // info 

    // some func that updates UI
    func updateUI(){
       
       let genericInfo = InfoManager.getInfo(info: .infoType)
       self.someNameOutletLabel.text = genericInfo.name
       self.secondNameOutletLabel?.text = (genericInfo as? AnotherInfo).secondName // here I don't like it
       if let someInfo = genericInfo as? SomeInfo{
          self.secondNameOutletLabel?.text = someInfo.thirdName // or like here I also don't like
       }
   }
}
```

Looking forward for other critics and advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by skipping the `InfoType` type and instead define what type being used from the given parameter or return value.

So the protocol becomes

```
protocol InfoManagerProtocol {
    static func getInfo<T: BaseInfo>() -> T?
    static func saveInfo <T: BaseInfo>(info: T)
}
```

and then the implementation. Note that instead of the `toString` in the enum I now use the classname itself as the key

```
class InfoManager: InfoManagerProtocol {
    static func getInfo<T: BaseInfo>() -> T? {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "\(T.self)") as? Data, let info = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data){
            return info
        }
        return nil
    }

    static func saveInfo<T>(info: T) where T : BaseInfo {
        if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(info){
            print(encodedData)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "\(T.self)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to use it (assuming that `init(from:)` has been properly implemented)

```
let dict: [String: String] = ["name": "Joe", "secondName": "Doe", "middleName": "Jr"]
let another = AnotherInfo(dict)
let some = SomeInfo(dict)

//Here the declaration of the argument tells the generic function what T is
InfoManager.saveInfo(info: another)
InfoManager.saveInfo(info: some)

//And here the declaration of the return value tells the generic function what T is
if let stored:AnotherInfo = InfoManager.getInfo() {
    print(stored, type(of: stored))
}
if let stored:SomeInfo = InfoManager.getInfo() {
    print(stored, type(of: stored))
}
```

Comment: Dont use `setValue` you should use `func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)`. Btw UserDefaults has a specific method to get data called `data(forKey:)`

Comment: It would be much better to make InfoManager methods to throw instead of failing silently

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `set` instead of `setValue` is definitely not just an improvement. Feel free to keep it as it is if you would like to. It is not even listed on Apples Documentation for setting UserDefaults value [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)